# How do you get access to the current System.Web.Routing.RequestContext from within a custom helper method in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing a helper method for ASP.NET MVC and I need to call `Url.Content` to get an appropriate URL for the context.  However, in order to create a new `UrlHelper()` I need to get the current `RequestContext` (`System.Web.Routing.RequestContext` to be precise) and I'm not sure how to grab it. Anyone know?

Comment: The context location will depend on what the extension method will be extending. Will this be used in a view, controller or elsewhere?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Noticed this was still unanswered. As of MVC 1.0 you can do:

```
public static string NewHelperMethod(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
```

Comment: I wanted to know how to do this from the controller, this answer gave me enough information to figure out that I wanted ControllerContext.RequestContext.

Answer (score 46):

If the current IHttpHandler is MvcHandler, you can use

```
((MvcHandler)HttpContext.Current.Handler).RequestContext
```

Comment: This is actually what I needed...from a truely static context

Answer (score 3):

You may have found an answer elsewhere, but here goes;

In a controller action, you can get to the current RequestContext like so:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(){
  var helper = new UrlHelper(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, just extend the HtmlHelper and the context is exposed in that way.  For example:

```
    public static string ExtensionMethodName(this HtmlHelper html,object o)
    {
        html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Uri ... etc    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a new one. Just extend the existing UrlHelper, just like you'd extend HtmlHelper:

```
public static string IdLink(this UrlHelper helper, Guid id)
    { //...
```

If you must use both HtmlHelper and UrlHelper, pass one of them as a regular (non-"this") argument.